# is Ember.Container a 'public enough' api to consider creating my own Ember.Container instance?

Tags: ember.js

I'm working on a module for use in Ember Application's that depends on Emberjs but doesn't depend on the existence of an Ember.Application instance -- at this point its a little bit speculative but in my mind I would like to be able to reuse some or all of this code in a non-browser environment (node) down the road.

Is there any reason not to create my own Ember.Container instance within my library for the purpose of having a flexible way to organize my library pieces internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know how to gauge "public enough". APIs that are not documented or are marked private are subject to change, and even public API may change with a major version bump (i.e. Ember 2.0). That said, the container is very useful code, and it is structured as a module, so if it was me, I would go for it and be resigned that I may need to either update or fork.